# Matlab strange message at startup

Tags: matlab

I don't know what makes this message come up at the time I open Matlab on Windows 8.1:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.mathworks.mde.cmdwin.XCmdWndView.getAfterPromptPoint(XCmdWndView.java:2473)
    at com.mathworks.mde.cmdhist.AltHistory.getPromptLocation(AltHistory.java:1391)
    at com.mathworks.mde.cmdhist.AltHistory.getPopupBounds(AltHistory.java:1407)
    at com.mathworks.mde.cmdhist.AltHistory._showPopup(AltHistory.java:1371)
    at com.mathworks.mde.cmdhist.AltHistory.access$5500(AltHistory.java:152)
    at com.mathworks.mde.cmdhist.AltHistory$HistoryClientListener$1.run(AltHistory.java:1864)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Unable to parse command history line: d>
Unable to parse command history line: d>
Unable to parse command history line: d>
Unable to parse command history line: /command>
Unable to parse command history line: d>
Unable to parse command history line: >
Unable to parse command history line: >
```

I use Matlab 2014a and don't know if it is well compatible with Windows 8.1.. Do you have any idea?

Comment: It should be compatible. That looks like a GUI loading error, but no idea.

Comment: If these messages always show up, you might want to reinstall both Java and MATLAB after uninstalling them. Great chance to install R2016b, the latest release since a few weeks. Something might be wrong at a low level on your Java/MATLAB installations, which might make anything you do in MATLAB unreliable. Also, the message states some command history lines are invalid. If you can miss your command history, delete it. Maybe that solves the other problems too, if the command history causes the exception.